# Junk output or random character in Data::Dumper output for Net::DNS::Resolver object

Tags: perl, object, dns

I am getting familiarized with the `Net::DNS` library in Perl and an object is created using

```
my $res = Net::DNS::Resolver->new();
```

However, simply trying to query a domain name shows a lot f junk values, though the output itself is correct. Here is the code snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use Net::DNS;
use Net::IP;
use Data::Dumper;
my $rr;

$domain = 'google.com';
my $res = Net::DNS::Resolver->new();

my $ns_req = $res->query($domain, "NS");
print "\n\n@@@\n".Dumper($ns_req)."\n@@@\n\n";
```

Here are 2 outputs for various domains tested against this object:
[image: google]
[image: domain using CF]

What are these junk values being displayed? Is there a way to clean up the output a bit in order to read the output properly?

Comment: Set `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1` to improve your output viewing experience.

Comment: Posting images of text is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dumping the internals of the object which include the buffer which holds the original response bytes.

You should use the API defined in the [module documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::DNS::Resolver) to access the information.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::DNS;

my $resolver = Net::DNS::Resolver->new;

my $result = $resolver->query('google.com', "NS");
$result->print;
```

Output:

```
;; Answer received from x.x.x.x (100 bytes)
;; HEADER SECTION
;;      id = 39595
;;      qr = 1  aa = 0  tc = 0  rd = 1  opcode = QUERY
;;      ra = 1  z  = 0  ad = 0  cd = 0  rcode  = NOERROR
;;      qdcount = 1     ancount = 4     nscount = 0     arcount = 0
;;      do = 0

;; QUESTION SECTION (1 record)
;; google.com.  IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION (4 records)
google.com.     21599   IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
google.com.     21599   IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
google.com.     21599   IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.     21599   IN      NS      ns3.google.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION (0 records)

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION (0 records)
```

The `query` method returns a [Net::DNS::Packet](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::DNS::Packet) which provides other methods to obtain specific parts of the response.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::DNS;

my $resolver = Net::DNS::Resolver->new;

my $result = $resolver->query('google.com', "NS");

for my $answer ($result->answer) {
    print $answer->nsdname, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
ns2.google.com
ns1.google.com
ns3.google.com
ns4.google.com
```

If you are interested in the contents of the binary buffer, `Net::DNS::Packet` has a `data` method which returns the contents of that buffer. As [RFC 1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) points out:

> ```
> 3.2. RR definitions
>
> 3.2.1. Format
>
> All RRs have the same top level format shown below:
>
>                                     1  1  1  1  1  1
>       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
>     +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
>     |                                               |
>     /                                               /
>     /                      NAME                     /
>     |                                               |
>     +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
>     |                      TYPE                     |
>     +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
>     |                     CLASS                     |
>     +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
>     |                      TTL                      |
>     |                                               |
>     +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
>     |                   RDLENGTH                    |
>     +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--|
>     /                     RDATA                     /
>     /                                               /
>     +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
>
>
> where:
>
> NAME            an owner name, i.e., the name of the node to which this
>                 resource record pertains.
>
> TYPE            two octets containing one of the RR TYPE codes.
>
> CLASS           two octets containing one of the RR CLASS codes.
>
> TTL             a 32 bit signed integer that specifies the time interval
>                 that the resource record may be cached before the source
>                 of the information should again be consulted.  Zero
>                 values are interpreted to mean that the RR can only be
>                 used for the transaction in progress, and should not be
>                 cached.  For example, SOA records are always distributed
>                 with a zero TTL to prohibit caching.  Zero values can
>                 also be used for extremely volatile data.
>
> RDLENGTH        an unsigned 16 bit integer that specifies the length in
>                 octets of the RDATA field.
>
> RDATA           a variable length string of octets that describes the
>                 resource.  The format of this information varies
>                 according to the TYPE and CLASS of the resource record.
> ```

You can examine the contents of `$result->data` by doing a hexdump:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                  

use strict;                                                          
use warnings;                                                        
use Net::DNS;                                                        

my $resolver = Net::DNS::Resolver->new;                              
my $result = $resolver->query('google.com', "NS");                   
print $result->data;
```

```
C:\...\t> perl tt.pl | xxd                               
00000000: 3256 8180 0001 0004 0000 0000 0667 6f6f  2V...........goo  
00000010: 676c 6503 636f 6d00 0002 0001 c00c 0002  gle.com.........  
00000020: 0001 0000 545f 0006 036e 7333 c00c c00c  ....T_...ns3....  
00000030: 0002 0001 0000 545f 0006 036e 7334 c00c  ......T_...ns4..  
00000040: c00c 0002 0001 0000 545f 0006 036e 7332  ........T_...ns2  
00000050: c00c c00c 0002 0001 0000 545f 0006 036e  ..........T_...n  
00000060: 7331 c00c                                s1..
```